How to change layout of headers in 'latest posts'
Hope you can help me! I would like to change the headers of all blog posts in 'recent posts' so they stand out more. Currently it is difficult to discern one post from the other. If the font of the headers would be a bit larger and have another font type than the post text, that would help a lot. When I change the typography via the menu on the right, all text changes (both headers and post text). See below the current code of 'latest-posts'. Should I add something there?
This is my website: https://terraformingmars.nl/blog/
<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><!-- wp:latest-posts {"postsToShow":50,"displayPostContent":true,"displayPostContentRadio":"full_post"} /--></div>
<!-- /wp:group -->


you can customise that with css like that : `.wp-block-latest-posts__post-title
{
background : #DDD;
padding : 1em;
border-radius : 1em;
margin-top : 3em;
font-size : 120%;
}
`

instead of using the latest posts block you could instead use a query block with a post title/excerpt inside, then every component would be its own block and you could adjust them however you want, e.g. the title would be a post title block. Latest posts is intended more as a list, e.g. bullet points, it's not intended to implement a full archive listing. Keep in mind too that the blocks within the latest posts on your page aren't properly rendered either for some reason, and are showing raw block markup complete with the HTML comments that are meant to be stripped out on render

Thanks Tom! Awesome, I will try it out.
